# Parse .0000 to 0 C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am parsing a CSV file into an array. One element of array is **.0000** I want to parse this as **0** but when I tried to parse **.0000** using following methods it returns **1**

```
fields[38].Substring(0,fields[38].IndexOf("."))  // expected 0, return 1

Convert.ToDecimal(fields[38])  // expected 0.00, return Exception

string.Equals(fields[38],".0000")   // expected true, return false

(int)decimal.Parse(fields[38])     // expected 0, return 1
```

Help Please !!!!!!!!

Comment: Could you add examples of some of the other values you are expecting to find in this column (fields[38])?

Comment: @ArunKumar, please make your sample code look like "string testValue="some text"; Convert.ToDecimal(testValue) // expected 0, return 1".

Comment: @DanielBallinger: Tim Schmelter's Answer works thanks

Comment: @ArunKumar Good to hear. If that is the case there should be a green tick that you can click next to his answer. With regards to your question. It would have been useful to know what other values you are parsing from this column and what data type you are trying to convert them to. I.e. Are you going to convert all the values to int (dropping the decimal places).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works, not sure if there's an easier way:

```
(int)(Decimal.Parse(val, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

[`Decimal.Parse Method (String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s84kdbzx)

Comment: @ArunKumar: `(int)(Decimal.Parse(".0000", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));` is 0 not 1, everywhere on the world.